# Better way to add new rows with particular elements to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a piece of code that generates a file containing the x, y, and z coordinates of a molecule. In order to make it a so-called "xyz file" (file.xyz), I need to add to this coordinate file two rows: 1) the top row contains just one number, the number of atoms; and 2) a comment line that could just be left empty (or say "Comment", or something). My variable called `xyz` looks like this

```
print(xyz)
```

gives

```
[['C\t' '-3.171284' '-0.739715' '0.525945']
 ['N\t' '-1.936557' '-0.026021' '0.202474']
 ['C\t' '-3.318626' '-1.011529' '2.043242']
 ['H\t' '-3.141982' '-1.708867' '0.014441']
 ['C\t' '-0.741793' '-0.677286' '0.129631']
 ['C\t' '0.462397' '0.162645' '-0.307099']
 ['N\t' '1.631324' '-0.381016' '0.368999']
 ['C\t' '0.559996' '0.147611' '-1.856616']
 ['H\t' '0.300250' '1.202007' '0.017165']
 ['H\t' '2.526359' '-0.068732' '0.017635']
 ['H\t' '1.567511' '-1.380033' '0.529925']
 ['O\t' '-0.635852' '-1.906598' '0.361505']
 ['H\t' '-2.000386' '0.966116' '0.025368']
 ['C\t' '-4.387139' '0.003940' '0.016667']
 ['O\t' '-4.106128' '1.302132' '-0.374180']
 ['O\t' '-5.528310' '-0.455442' '-0.014098']
 ['H\t' '-4.923659' '1.755530' '-0.673289']
 ['H\t' '0.662313' '-0.882934' '-2.213554']
 ['H\t' '1.440364' '0.716422' '-2.178038']
 ['H\t' '-0.324051' '0.596253' '-2.326387']
 ['H\t' '-2.470166' '-1.616700' '2.369974']
 ['H\t' '-4.246949' '-1.555151' '2.240849']
 ['H\t' '-3.326402' '-0.071610' '2.604601']]
```

The number of atoms is given by `len(xyz)`. My desirable output should be

```
print(xyz)

[[23 '' '' '']
 ['Comment' '' '' '']
 ['C\t' '-3.171284' '-0.739715' '0.525945']
 ['N\t' '-1.936557' '-0.026021' '0.202474']
 ['C\t' '-3.318626' '-1.011529' '2.043242']
 ['H\t' '-3.141982' '-1.708867' '0.014441']
 ['C\t' '-0.741793' '-0.677286' '0.129631']
 ['C\t' '0.462397' '0.162645' '-0.307099']
 ['N\t' '1.631324' '-0.381016' '0.368999']
 ['C\t' '0.559996' '0.147611' '-1.856616']
 ['H\t' '0.300250' '1.202007' '0.017165']
 ['H\t' '2.526359' '-0.068732' '0.017635']
 ['H\t' '1.567511' '-1.380033' '0.529925']
 ['O\t' '-0.635852' '-1.906598' '0.361505']
 ['H\t' '-2.000386' '0.966116' '0.025368']
 ['C\t' '-4.387139' '0.003940' '0.016667']
 ['O\t' '-4.106128' '1.302132' '-0.374180']
 ['O\t' '-5.528310' '-0.455442' '-0.014098']
 ['H\t' '-4.923659' '1.755530' '-0.673289']
 ['H\t' '0.662313' '-0.882934' '-2.213554']
 ['H\t' '1.440364' '0.716422' '-2.178038']
 ['H\t' '-0.324051' '0.596253' '-2.326387']
 ['H\t' '-2.470166' '-1.616700' '2.369974']
 ['H\t' '-4.246949' '-1.555151' '2.240849']
 ['H\t' '-3.326402' '-0.071610' '2.604601']]
```

---

My solution (which feels a bit clumsy):

```
nbofatoms = len(xyz)
xyz = np.insert(xyz, 0, '', axis=0)
xyz = np.insert(xyz, 0, '', axis=0)
xyz[0][0] = nbofatoms
xyz[1][0] = 'Comment'
```

So, is there a better way?

Answer (score -1):

You could do it inline to condense your code:

```
xyz = np.insert(xyz, 0, str(nbofatoms), axis=0)
xyz = np.insert(xyz, 0, 'comment', axis=0)
```

Comment: Firstly, your order leads to the number of atoms being at the comment line, and the comment line is the first line. Not what I want. Besides, this adds the number "23" to all four elements of the second line, and the string "comment" to all four elements of the first row. I just want to add "23" and "Comment" to the first element of these rows.